# Use a String as a Seed for a Randomiser

Tags: php

It is possible to use a string as a randomiser seed to generate a number between two values in PHP.

For example:

```
$seed = 'John';

srand($seed);

echo rand(1, 10);
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this?

Comment: The function uses an integer.

Comment: then I think you can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-random-seed.php

Comment: You can go over the string char for char and convert that to an integer (i.e. with [ord()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ord.php))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5477196/2943403, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37058319/2943403,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the hash of the input string to get an integer (with [`crc32()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php) in example) and then, use that number as seed :

```
<?php
$StringSeed = "John";
$IntSeed = crc32($StringSeed);

echo "Hash Value : $IntSeed" . PHP_EOL;

srand($IntSeed);

echo rand(1, 10); // 8
echo rand(1, 10); // 4
echo rand(1, 10); // 10
```

[Try it yourself](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d06ede3127c26a2a2e620f0ec2ad3ef1b83ebd7c)